# NSString to float...what happens if NSString is not numerical and contains alphanumeric characters?

Tags: ios, nsstring, floating-point, type-conversion, alphanumeric

if 
           `NSString sample = @"1sa34hjh#@";

          Float 64 floatsample = [sample floatValue];`

what happens? what does floatsample contain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

**Return Value**

The floating-point value of the receiver’s text as a float, skipping whitespace at the beginning of the string. Returns HUGE_VAL or –HUGE_VAL on overflow, 0.0 on underflow.

*Also returns **0.0** if the receiver **doesn’t begin with** a valid text representation of a floating-point number.*

The best way to figure out the return value is to check the return value yourself. You can create a small program and save it as a file with a .m extension. Here's a sample:

```
// floatTest.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main() {
    NSString *sample = @"1sa34hjh#@";
    float floatsample = [sample floatValue];
    printf("%f", floatsample);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it on the command-line using clang and linking with the Foundation framework.

```
clang floatTest.m -framework foundation -o floatTest
```

Then run the executable and see the output.

```
./floatTest
```

The printed value is `1.000000`. So to answer your question, if the string starts with a number, then the number portion of the string will be taken and converted to float. Same rules as above apply on overflow or underflow.

If creating the files seems like a hassle, you might like this blog post on [minimalist Cocoa programming](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html).

Comment: thank you very much! :) next time i'll post only if i don't understand the documentation. One question-if it returns 0.0 both times, we can't differentiate what the issue is, right?

Comment: your input actually returns `1.0`, not `0.0`. But to determine if the given is a valid floating point number without any junk characters, use `scanFloat:` in  [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Some good folks have already done this for us for many languages at  [rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_a_string_is_numeric#Objective-C).

Comment: "your input actually returns 1.0, not 0.0" Could you please explain that? I didn't fully understand.

Comment: @Namratha - since `"1sa34hjh#"` starts with a valid number - `1`, that part of the string is parsed and everything else is ignored. If, however, the string did not start with a number, for ex., `"a123.45"`, then `0` would have been returned.