# How do I get a float value from a text field?

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, uitextfield

I've seen others ask similar questions, but none of the answers have worked for me; I get the message "Expected ';' at end of declaration list". Can someone walk me through what I'm supposed to do? (This is my first question here, so I'm sorry if I did something wrong.)

Comment: Usually a good idea to show the code and give a little bit more detail about where you think something has gone wrong. Allows people to point you in the right direction. 

Also, helps to show what research you have done yourself.

Comment: And don't use the "xcode" tag for non-Xcode questions.

Answer (score 11):

```
float yourVariable = [yourTextField.text floatValue];
```

Make sure you add validations to your textfield. If you have any non-numeric it will return 0.

[How to convert NSString value @"3.45" into float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610359/how-to-convert-nsstring-value-3-45-into-float)

I also gone through following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965652/nsstring-to-float-what-happens-if-nsstring-is-not-numerical-and-contains-alpha) which says  `returns 0.0 if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid text representation of a floating-point number`.

Answer (score 1):

```
float floatsample = [sampletextfield.text floatValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *floatFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[floatFormatter numberFromString:textField.text];
```

Assuming `textField` is your textField. Then you can check `floatFormatter` for a nil `NSNumber` if it can't parse the string properly.